# Signed APK - Password verification failed

Tags: android, apk

I have released my app in google play store and now I want to update it.
I should enter the key password and key store password.

I'm sure the password are correct I even checked it in

...gradle\5.4.1\executionHistory\executionHistory.bin

I don't want to create new signed key , but i don't have any idea what's wrong.

I tried cleaning the project and do it again. Same error

In the log :

rg.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Failed to read key from store "C:...\ KeyStore\MyKeyStore.jks": Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect